# Nginx 111 error

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to use Nginx for reverse proxy with a node app. My dev environment is setup in docker.
This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services: 
  web:
    build: ./nginx
    links:
      - engine
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
      - "8081:443"
  engine:
    build: ./engine
    volumes: 
      - ./engine:/var/www/engine
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
```

The dockerfile for the engine(node) service

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

# Install Node.js and other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install curl && \
    apt-get -y install git && \
    apt-get -y install wget && \
    curl -sl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash - && \
    apt-get -y install python build-essential nodejs

# Install yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install yarn && \
    export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"

# Install pm2, gulp, typescript
RUN yarn global add pm2 && \
    yarn global add gulp && \
    yarn global add typescript && \
    yarn global add typings

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/engine

# Install dependecies
RUN yarn install

# Expose export
EXPOSE 5000

# Run app
CMD yarn start
```

the nginx dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

ADD ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /var/www
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    upstream app {
        server engine:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a basic node serve running in the engine service

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(5000, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:5000/');
```

I can see the log message in the container output

Trying to access the engine service via http://localhost:8080 results in 502 bad gateway, and the logs say

```
[error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.25.0.2:5000/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/
```

I can't quite figure out which config is wrong and is causing the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, turns out my node app has explicitly bound to 'localhost'.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(5000);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:5000/');
```